# Modal input versus input value trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal here to proceed the save confirmation the value of input modal while return to input HTML. simple copy paste. here's my codes

```
<div class="modal-container">
    <div class="mHeader">
        Enter your Name: <input id="getName" type="text" class="0"></input>
    </div>
    <span class="button_confirm">
        <button class="bnt1" id="paid"> Paid </button>
        <button class="bnt1" id="save"> save </button>
        <a href="#">Close </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Then here's my JS Jquery codes

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#save").click(function(){

        var person = document.getElementById("getName").value
            $(this).val(person);
        alert("Save!! " + person);

    });


    $("#paid").click(function(){

        alert("Paid!!");
    });
});
```

just leave the comments in saving I'be fix with the payments

and here's my HTML inputs

```
<a href="#cats"><input type="text"><span>0-1</span></a>
<a href="#cats"><input type="text"><span>0-2</span></a>
<a href="#cats"><input type="text"><span>0-3</span></a>
<a href="#cats"><input type="text"><span>0-4</span></a>
```

if i click the HTML inputs Modal will appear to input their names and save! if click save then the value will write in input of span html

Thanks Guys...

Comment: What's your problem clearly?

Comment: My problem is...
How do I code's if the input of modal has a value, then i click save. to save the value into input type ="text".

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the following lines

`var person = document.getElementById("getName").value`

`$(this).val(person);`

`alert("Save!! " + person);`

with

`var person = document.getElementById("getName").value`

`if(person.length) {
    $(this).val(person);
    alert("Save!! " + person);
}`

Comment: I need to put the value of modals that i save in the HTML input <span> thats my reason why Iam stock hehe ^^

Comment: You wrote "How do I code's if the input of modal has a value" . So, I suggested the fix. Can you mention which span you want to populate or what is the way you would be inserting values in spans ?